# Java mail how use proxy?

Tags: java, email, proxy, jakarta-mail

Need to send message (smtp) using a proxy, code below, the proxy is completely ignored, what to do?

```
Properties props = new Properties();

            System.setProperty("mail.socket.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.socket.debug", "true");
            if (_config.getIsProxy()) {
                props.put("mail.smtp.socks.host", proxyHost);
                props.put("mail.smtp.socks.port", proxyPost);

            }
            props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", _config.getTimeout()*1000);
            props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", _config.getTimeout()*1000);
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.store.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", server);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12097764/1511077

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending java mail from with in a proxy server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093242/sending-java-mail-from-with-in-a-proxy-server)

Comment: [Get rid of the socket factory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  If it still doesn't work, post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  The proxy you've configured is a SOCKS proxy, not just an HTTP proxy, right?  See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy) for more details.