# Issue in sending mail ( connection refused) using java mail from corporate network

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-mail

I have written piece of code for sending mail (smtp, tls enabled). It works fine when my m/c(running this code) is connected to any commercial network. However, when I am in office(corporate network), I receive following error while executing same code:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1545)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:453)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at Mailer.sendEmail(Mailer.java:129)
    at Mailer.main(Mailer.java:36)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:267)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1511)
```

To analyze further, I took network traces(wireshark), I saw that server is not responding to TCP SYN sent by the client(here my code). I understand, this could be due to network firewall or other network policy enforcement functions.

Do you have any thoughts, how I can move forward on this ?

Here is the code:

/*
 * Description: This class presents the email generation and sending logic. 
 * @version | Date: 0.1 | Jan 29, 2017
 */

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Mailer
{
    Session mailSession;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,    MessagingException, IOException
    {
        Mailer javaEmail = new Mailer();
        javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
        javaEmail.draftEmailMessage();
        javaEmail.sendEmail();
    }

    private void setMailServerProperties()
    {
        Properties emailProperties = System.getProperties();

        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        emailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    }
    private MimeMessage draftEmailMessage() throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException
    {
        String[] toEmails = { "x.y@dd.com","xxyy@gmail.com" };
        Address addRess = new InternetAddress("sender@dd.com");
        Address[] fromAddress = {addRess};
        String emailSubject = "Import update";
        String emailBody = "whether is called";
        MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        /**
         * Set the mail recipients
         * */
        for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++)
        {
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
        }
        emailMessage.addFrom(fromAddress);
        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
        /**
         * If sending HTML mail
         * */

        // Create the message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Now set the actual message
        messageBodyPart.setText("This is Will be the meessage body");

        // Create a multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Part two is attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = "D:\\Tradfri.java";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Part three is the embedded body
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String cid = (Integer.toString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 60000 + 1)));
        System.out.println("CID is " + cid);
        messageBodyPart.setText(""
          + "<html>"
          + " <body>"
          + "  <p>Here is my image:</p>"
          + "  <img src=\"cid:" + cid + "\" />"
          + " </body>"
          + "</html>", 
          "US-ASCII", "html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.attachFile("C:\\Users\\MyPlace\\Pictures\\ww.png");
        messageBodyPart.setContentID("<" + cid + ">");
        messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Send the complete message parts
        emailMessage.setContent(multipart);

        return emailMessage;
    }

    private void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException
    {
        /**
         * Sender's credentials
         * */
        String fromUser = "sender@dd.com";
        String fromUserEmailPassword = "(XXXXXX1@)";

        String emailHost = "smtp.office365.com";

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
        /*
         * Draft the message
         * */
        MimeMessage emailMessage = draftEmailMessage();

        /**
         * Send the mail
         * */

        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: contact your network administrator for correct smtp host and port.

Comment: Ask your network administrator for help.  It's a bit pointless asking the Stack Overflow community to guess at how your network's been set up.

Comment: Are you sure it's TLS and not SSL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works and the issue is the corporate firewall blocking outgoing connections, either to the server or to port 587.  Only the corporate network administrator can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure Java mail to connect through a proxy server.

Note that Java mail doesn't support HTTP proxy, so you have to configure it to use a SOCKS proxy.

If your corporate network does not have a SOCKS proxy enabled then some alternatives:

- Ask the network administrator to open the outgoing port from your server.
- Defeat the HTTP proxy by running a SOCKS proxy locally on the server that proxies through the HTTP proxy on the corporate network. 'cntlm' has this ability. Beware though this is likely against some network policy.

See also this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12097764/3216618

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Avast Anti-Virus was not letting me to connect. these type of software can be the cause for these types of errors.