# java outlook send mail

Tags: java, email, outlook

I'm trying to send mail through outlook but getting error as below.

```
package test.first.javamail;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendAttachmentInEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        // String to = "sagapawar1234@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "abcd@outlook.com";
        final String password = "*****";// change accordingly

        // Check how many arguments were passed in
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Please run Sendmail jar as: java -jar SendMail.jar <recivers@gmail.com> <path of attachment file>");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String to = args[0];
        String attachment_path = args[1];
        final String username = from;
        ;// change accordingly

        System.out.println("Trying to send mail to : " + to + "\n");
        // final String username = "abcd";// change accordingly
        // final String password = "******";// change accordingly
        System.out.println("Please wait for a moment, we are checking creadentials...! \n");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
//      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");smtp.office365.com
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
//      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
//      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");

        // Get the Session object.
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        System.out.println("Seat tight your identity has been proved and mail is just on the way...! ");
        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Now set the actual message
            messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

            // Create a multipar message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String filename = attachment_path;// "C:/Users/swapnil.kotwal/Desktop/buildsuccess.txt";Azure.png
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Send the complete message parts
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout -1;
      nested exception is:
            java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at test.first.javamail.SendAttachmentInEmail.main(SendAttachmentInEmail.java:104)
    Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout -1;
      nested exception is:
            java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
            at test.first.javamail.SendAttachmentInEmail.main(SendAttachmentInEmail.java:99)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:331)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2066)
```

I believe the code is proper but not sure what exactly blocking the mail delivery ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check whether the SMTP server and port are correct.

Comment: I had very similar Stack trace, after much fretting, realised I had a space on the end of the hostname in the properties file. `spring.mail` was taking this as part of the hostname and failing to resolve it. Though I see it is not your issue, you get:  
`com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587;`  
whereas I got:  
`com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com , 587;`  
It may help someone else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
```

**I think you need to check few things**

- SMTP server should be appropriate
- Some organisations has blocked `587` port number, please check with your IT team if that port is open to communicate with given SMTP
  server

If you get the appropriate open port,the issue suppose to get resolved.

Basically work on this properties

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
//      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");smtp.office365.com
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //change this port
```

If there is any proxy related settings your org have, you can refer this answers as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/12097764/1665592

Comment: May be the proxy is refusing the connection. So you need to set the proxy too.

Comment: Thanks, given link to proxy settings