# Smtp connection outlook with java

Tags: java, outlook, smtp

I have created Session successfully.

I am able to get IMAP urlName but when trying to make connection of Store for outlook, I get an error.

What hostname will come in parameter for outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code to connect outlook:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
//      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");smtp.office365.com
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");//This is hostname
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //change this port
```

Before connection, You should check few things:

1. SMTP server should be appropriate.
2. Some organisations has blocked 587 port number, please check with your IT team if

that port is open to communicate with given SMTP server.

For more information, you could refer to this link:

[java outlook send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200210/java-outlook-send-mail)